# source tree how to discard an un pushed commit and go step back

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

i am using Sourcetree git client with git lab. I am new to version control. Is there any way to discard my commit and go back. I haven't pushed that commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just right click on your commit and reverse it.

Comment: Just a note, this is like using `git revert` which creates a revert commit. Better solution is to use git reset given in below answer by @mattmilten

Comment: Source-tree way of doing git reset is, right click on previous commit where you want to be and select `reset <branch-name> to this commit`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about Sourcetree, but in "normal" git, i.e. command line git, you would simply do a soft reset:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This will remove the commit but will leave the working directory, i.e. your actual files, as they are. You can then commit these changes in a new commit.

Comment: Shots fired! But @mattmilten has a point, once you are more comfortable with source tree, moving to the command line will help you get faster and more fluent with git

Comment: this helped me a lot. I use Sourcetree for git operation. I soft reset a commit but could not see the differences. Also, if I pushed it, it would look async to dev. However, after I do sort reset without pushing it, I typed this in terminal, and my reverted changes appeared without being async to main.